# SVG tag's children have default placement outside of parent

Tags: css, html, svg

I'm trying to learn how to use the HTML5 svg tag. When I open this in Chrome and Firefox

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <svg width="200" height="200">
            <text>Hello World</text>
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

nothing is displayed. After clicking "Inspect Element" I see that the text element has a default placement outside the svg element. How can I change the svg element so all its descendant elements start at the point (0,0) in their respective parent?

Comment: You need to look into `viewbox` - http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-coordinate-system.html

Comment: If this is true, why doesn't exactly a quarter of "Hello World" show up? Does the text element work a bit differently?

Comment: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/text-element.html#text-example

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `xmlns` attribute to `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg` on the SVG element ?

If you ommit that attribute, the browser may not detect the content as SVG.
Basically, the `xmlns` attribute defines the XML namespace of the element.

Answer (score 0):

SVG elements are not automatically laid out like HTML.  All SVG graphic elements have to be specifically positioned using coordinates.

`<text>` elements need to have their start position (`x` and `y`) specified.  If you don't specify them, they default to `0`, which corresponds to the top left corner of the SVG.

So to fix this, give your text element start coordinates.

```html
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <svg width="200" height="200">
            <text x="10" y="50">Hello World</text>
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```